# Hadoop: Run two M/R jobs on same data or ChainMap with a barrier of synchronization

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a problem which requires me to filter a large amount of data, tens of terabytes, in an iterative process. Due to the size, I would like to do the computation in 2 consecutive map phases so that the data doesn't need to be retransfered across the network.

So the steps in the algorithm are 1) analyze all data and make a decision, 2) rerun on the same data and do a filtering process based on the decision from 1.

I figure there are two ways to solve this, but each seems to have large issues.

1) Solution, ChainMapper. Problem: The first mapper needs to complete entirely before the second starts.

2) Solution, two jobs. Problem: the data gets retransfered across the network as data is deleted between jobs.

I'm sure there is something I'm missing, but I could really use some help!

Thanks

Comment: If you have to have all data to make the decision that defines the second step then why is it a problem that the first phase must completely finish first? Seems required. Or else this is not quite rewired and this is the key to your question.

Comment: Because the decision is based on looking at all the key/values.  So until I've seen all of the key/value pairs, I can't say what the decision would be. So I was thinking Map -> make decision based on mappers -> Map2.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your reply.  Yes, I WANT the first map to complete first.  I just don't know how to make that happen without resending all the data across the network twice.

Comment: This avoids sending data around, since the mappers can spawn on top of the data from the last mapper. But... I get a sense that phase 2 depends on the results of all output of phase 1, whereas a mapper sees only a slice of all the data. You may need to specify your actual problem to understand what is possible.

Comment: You are right. Phase 2 depends on the results of all output of phase1.  I can actually store this output in counters so passing is not an issue.  What is important is that I don't overload the network, and I'm pretty sure the data is getting transfered once per job I run, when I would really just like to act on the same data as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your clarifications: you can't use `ChainMapper`, but it is exactly *because* it does not operate by applying mapper 1 to all keys, waiting, then applying mapper 2. It applies a chain of maps to each input key. Some will finish phase 1 and 2 before others even start. But you are right that it doesn't cause more data to go across the network; here it's not even written to disk!

Since you need phase 1 to finish, you really need to finish the Map phase before doing anything else with phase 2. Do phase 1 in the `Mapper`, phase 2 in the `Reducer`. That's simplest.

Strangely, it might be faster to have two Map/Reduces, but without a `Reducer`. The `Reducer` can be a no-op, `Reducer.class`. Call `setNumReduceTasks(0)`. You avoid the shuffle phase this way. It won't copy data around to reducers but just dump to HDFS.

Your next mappers will spawn on top of the HDFS data, in general. No extra transfer there.

I don't think you're going to avoid some data transfer here to reorganize and remarshall data but I think it's unlikely to dominate your calculation.

Comment: So this sounds like the way to go, but I just ran a test and I'm not sure this is working to not transfer the data twice.  So what I did was create a 1 Terabyte test set, using Teragen.  Then I created a Program where I set the number of reducers to 0. From here I did a Job that had the first Mapper emit nothing, did job.waitUntilCompletion(), then I did a second job right afterwards with another Mapper that emitted nothing. Both Map times took about 7 minutes to complete.  Doing the same thing but just using a Chainmapper between the mappers only takes 7 minutes total.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think ChainMapper is an option given your requirements. You need phase 1 to finish before phase 2, and that's not what it does. The 7 minutes is pure overhead. You can tune to get that down some. You can also try a Mapper + Reducer instead.

Comment: The ChainMapper is definitely not an option, I was just using it as a comparison. I'll try the reducer but ideally I wouldn't have to go through the shuffle/sort computation. Also ideally it would use the same node for both mapper and the reducer to cut down on the network traffic.  So if you know how to do either of those two things let me know.  But, I think your answer gives the 2 ways to go about this, unfortunately it's not really ideal for me but I think those are hadoop limitations, not your answers.